# Eigenvectors of bipartite graph using bi-adjacency matrix

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I was trying the calculate the eigenvectors of the adjacency matrix of a bipartite graph by utilizing the bi-adjacency matrix given by $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. The adjacency matrix of the whole graph can be defined as $$A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & B \\ B^\top & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

If $B$ has  SVD given by $B = U\Sigma V^\top$, then the eigendecomposition of $A$ is given by $$A = \begin{bmatrix}\bar U & \bar U \\ \bar V & -\bar V\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} +\Sigma & \\ & -\Sigma\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \bar U & \bar U \\ \bar V & -\bar V\end{bmatrix}^\top$$ where $\bar{U} = U/\sqrt{2}$.

My main aim to calculate the eigenvalues by only using the bi-adjacency matrix $B$ since $A$ might be too big. I was trying to verify this by using libraries like pytorch. First I compute $U,V$ using SVD  and then I am trying to compare them with the eigenvectors of $A$ by doing eigendecomposition of $A$. However, the vectors do not match. Is there anything I am missing?

Image source: https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6073

Comment: The same article with a better-looking aspect [here](https://www.internetmathematicsjournal.com/api/v1/articles/1575-exploiting-the-structure-of-bipartite-graphs-for-algebraic-and-spectral-graph-theory-applications.pdf).

Comment: If the eigenvalues have multiplicity, then eigenvectors found by different methods might just end up different. Can you provide more details?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you for the reply! What are the actual eigenvectors in that case then? Do the above eigenvectors hold true?

Comment: What do you mean, "the actual eigenvectors"? Anyway, certainly the eigendecomposition of $A$ given in the question is valid, you can check it by multiplying it out.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I meant if different methods are giving me different eigenvectors (for example pytorch's eigendecomposition) which one should I use

Comment: Without you providing any details of the other methods, I can't say if you're using them correctly or not - but in principle, any of them should be fine!